# Change text highlight settings in Visual Studio Code for macOS

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studi Code for macOS (Version: 1.72.2), how do I change the settings for how certain text is highlighted. In the include screenshot, the highlight for the Find result (the word buret in buret.addEventListener is barely noticeable among the other highlighted words (button, enable, etc.)

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Searched through settings which is far too big to easily find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize your theme colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color). The colors you are looking for are your [editor colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors).

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette and run the `Preferences: Open JSON Settings` command. Add the following lines to your configuration:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.findMatchBackground": "#00ff00",
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#ff0000",
},
```

This will change the background color of the active find match to green and of all other find matches to red. Adjust the colour values as you like.